# Drupal book outline only for nodes of specific type

Tags: user-accounts, drupal

I have a Drupal site, which allows all logged in users to add and edit book pages. On the permissions page I have enabled they may also administer book outlines.

The problem is that they can do this for all nodes, even forum topics and pages, and blog entries. Does anyone know how I can fix this, so that people can only change this for book pages?

Comment: Perhaps link the website? Since if I google Drupal I hardly understand your question

Comment: Sorry, my website is only on a local website. If you want to know what Drupal is, check http://www.drupal.org/

Comment: Shouldn't this question be rather on serverfault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into the acl modules. There are acl modules that allow you a finer granularity which allows you to say certain users can only do certain tasks with nodes of a certain type.

Answer (score 1):

Better, you can go to user management => permissions. from that, uncheck the relevant box in the authenticated users column. Instance "Administer nodes" (All Appropriate edit permissions). Similarly for your forum & blog modules.

Answer (score 0):

In User Management -> Permissions be sure to uncheck the relevant boxes in the authenticated users column, for instance "administer nodes" (and all the appropriate edit permissions) under node module and similarly for your forum and blog modules.

Comment: Sorry, didn't help. They are unchecked already.

Comment: Hmm, only others things offhand I can think to check are (a) to make sure all the permissions set for authenticated users are correct and (b) that the users who are able to do this editing where they shouldn't be aren't accidentally set up with any role that they shouldn't have.  And that you're not inadvertently logged in as admin while replicating this behavior, but rather logged in as an authorized user.